# Google Maps API Black Screen

Tags: android, google-maps

Has anybody had a problem with Google Maps giving a black screen today?  I am working on a project with some co-workers and suddenly the map is showing a black screen.  When we do a fresh install of the app it works fine the first time, then when it is rebuilt it shows the black screen.  This is all being done in the CLI interface for Titanium (joy).  If anybody else has had this problem please respond.  Not sure if this is a Google API Issue, or Titanium issue, we are trying to narrow it down at the moment.

Comment: no problems here at this time.

Comment: I should also say we tested on two different Galaxy S3 devices, both running Jelly Bean, with the latest Google Map update from August 16th 2013.  We tested on an HTC Device running ICS and it worked fine.  So not sure if this is a Jelly Bean problem, or a Samsung issue.  Regardless it sucks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with
android:anyDensity="false" in the manifest.
i have just encountered the same behavior.
if you set android:anyDensity="true" it works fine.

Comment: Tried that, it did work however it destroyed almost every other view in the app.  The map looks very nice now, but still, gotta figure something out.  I appreciate the suggestion sir.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot and many hit and trial found issue in `Manifest.xml`. I moved this code from `Application` tag to `Activity` tag in `Manifest`.

Issue was in `Manifest`.

```
<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

Remove from `Manifest` and Use in the `Activity`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mycompayname.activities.SignUpActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird hacky solution, but try putting a clear image over the top of the mapview.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView123"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/transparent" />
```

Doing so has solved the blackness of google maps in various situations, especially when animations are involved.

Comment: Did you put it after the mapview? No guarantees, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation for anydensity, you will see that it is strongly suggested it stays on. so my suggestion is to fix your other views.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem: my application worked fine for several months and a few weeks ago I saw the black screen when I loaded the map. I suppose that it has been a Google Maps update....

I've fixed it invoking the method setZOrderOnTop(true) in the constructor of the class that I've implemented to display the map (it inherits of the SurfaceView class).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but,I found out that WebViews (even on other fragments) sometime "crash" the GL engine or something which results in black screens in the MapView. I found in LogCat this:

```
09-30 10:58:17.765: E/libEGL(29805): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-30 10:58:17.765: W/Adreno200-EGL(29805): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3421>: EGL_BAD_CONTEXT
09-30 10:58:17.765: W/HardwareRenderer(29805): EGL error: EGL_BAD_CONTEXT
09-30 10:58:17.775: W/HardwareRenderer(29805): Mountain View, we've had a problem here. Switching back to software rendering.
```

To fix this when the WebView is detached I call the destroy function, in a Fragment so:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (webView != null) {
        webView.destroy();
        webView = null;
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Maybe it'll solve the issue for you as well.